# Parallel smaller non-persistent requests vs Sequential non-persistent HTTP requests?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, protocols, network-share

Let us assume we have 10 files, 100kb each stored in a server. 
A wireless link with a transmission rate of 200bps between a server and a client which are 5 meters away from each other.

Let us assume that x parallel connections get equal amount of share of the link. e.g for 10 file requests, we would get 20bps per request.

Assuming these files are requested using an HTTP protocol:

**The client wants all the files, do parallel requests make any sense against sequential requests, provided that we can only have non-persistent HTTP connections?**

If my reasoning is correct, it would take 2RTT + 100000/200 to transfer a file from the server to the client (if we assume the propagation delay is negligible and that the other delays are also insignificant, and that a triple TCP handshake takes 2RTT).

Therefore, sequentially, it would take (10 (2RTT + 1500)) = 20RTT + 15000 seconds.

And in parallel, if we assume other delays are negligible and that transmitting a small package also takes insignificant times, it would take:

total bitrate/10 = 20bps for each parallel request. Thus:

2RTT + 100000/20 = 2RTT + 15000 in total, because we are doing this in parallel for each file.

So 2RTT + 15000 vs 20RTT + 15000 sounds like it is indeed more efficient.

Am I doing this wrong? Can I get some insight?